# Probability zero but possible

Tags: probability

I would like to get an answer from someone who knows mathematical definitions, 
Q: is this claim: "it's possible for something to have probability zero (not approaching, actually zero) and yet be possible." Correct?

Comment: Yes, just as in integration theory, aset may have measur $0$ without being empty.

Comment: Correct. The probability of a line going through any particular point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is zero, but obviously it's possible because infinitely many lines go through each point.

Comment: Only in the discrete case, $P(A)=0$ means that $A$ is the impossible event.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. $0$ probability doesn't mean impossible. The classic example is the following:

> The probability of any given number being chosen from a random number generator over the reals is $0$ (it couldn't be anything else, since there are an infinite number of reals) but the probability of some number being chosen is $1$, so clearly it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{P}(X=0.5)$ where $X$ is a uniform distribution between $]0,1[$